# Subtract a column vector from matrix at specified vector of columns using only broadcast

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

I want to subtract a column vector from a  numpy matrix using another vector which is index of columns where the first column vector needs to be subtracted from the main matrix. For eg.

```
M = array([[  1,   2,   1,   1],
           [  2,   1,   1,   1],
           [  1,   1,   2,   1],
           [  2,   1,   1,   1],
           [  1,   1,   1,   2]])  # An example matrix

V = array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) # An example column vector

I = array([0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3]) # The index maxtrix
```

Now I want to subtract V from M at column numbers given in I.
For eg. I[0] is 0, so subtract V from first column (zero index) of matrix M.

Similarly I[1] = 3, subtract V from fourth column (three index) of matrix M.

At the end of operation, since 3 occurs 4 times in I, so V will be subtracted from **third** column i.e. last column of M- 4 times.

I need to do this using only broadcast, no loops.

I have tried the following:

```
M[:, I] - V[np.newaxis, :].T
```

but it ends up broadcasting resultant matrix to have more columns than there are in M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use `bincount` and `outer`

```
>>> M - np.outer(V, np.bincount(I, None, M.shape[1]))
array([[ 0,  1,  0, -3],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  1, -3],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -2]])
```

or `subtract.at`

```
>>> out = M.copy()
>>> np.subtract.at(out, (np.s_[:], I), V[:, None])
>>> out
array([[ 0,  1,  0, -3],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  1, -3],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -2]])
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`np.subtract.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) on transposed view of `M` -

```
np.subtract.at(M.T,I,V)
```

Comment: extending `I` seems unnecessary - still +1 for brevity